Как отличить, когда "ведь" частица, а когда подчинительный союз?
Бывает ли, чтоб "ведь" отделялось запятой на стыке союзов? Если можно, с примерами.

Примеры, где бы с двух сторон отделялось или с одной? на стыке двух союзов включая ведь (но ведь он ушел) или между двумя другими союзами (но ведь если он ушел)? Как отличить? Ну если ведь находится рядом с но, или другими союзами, то не хочется называть его союзом. Если в середине, а не  вначале односоставного предложения, то тоже союзом как-то не получается назвать. "Он ведь ушел". - частица, "Ведь он ушел" - союз.

Можно с двух сторон, можно с одной. Главное, чтоб после "ведь" была запятая.

ОБЗОР ТЕМЫ

О частице ведь в Сети много информации: Справочник по пунктуации, словарь, различные учебные и грамматические материалы,  в том числе на форуме вопрос обсуждался часто. Но вот ясности до конца все-таки нет.

Начнем с семантики. Ведь — от слова ведать, то есть это отсыл к известной информации. Основное значение частицы усилительное, но она также используется в предложениях с причинными, уступительными и условными отношениями.

В учебнике по синтаксису слово ведь упомянуть как разговорный союз-частица в теме СПП со значением причины, и тогда частица самостоятельно выполняет роль союза. Но чаще она является дополнительным структурным элементом, в том числе как вторая часть двойного союза.

Откуда такое разнообразие? Сравним к примеру, значение уступки и причины.


Как я мог забыть, я ведь (= если я) знал это! Это БСП, отношения уступительные, слово ведь в роли структурного элемента, но на правах союза.
"Знай, близка судьба твоя, Ведь царевна эта – я". Это разговорный союз-частица в СПП со значением причины во второй части.
Перефразируем басню: Ведь (= хотя) сколько раз твердили миру,
Что лесть3 гнусна, вредна; но только все не впрок...
Теперь слово ведь переместилось в первую часть СПП со значением уступки, где входит  в двойной союз ВЕДЬ (ХОТЯ)...НО.
Как отличить союз  от частицы? Во всех названных темах примеров более чем достаточно, а ответ такой: определите грамматику предложения, и тогда роль слова ведь будет ясна.
ПУНКТУАЦИЯ
Зачем нам все это знать?  Конечно же для того, чтобы разобраться  с запятыми. Вот рекомендация, с которой я однозначно соглашусь:
Ещё одно важное замечание: слово ведь ни при каких условиях не выступает в роли вводного, а это означает, что обособление его с двух сторон является ошибкой.
Если такое обособление встречается в литературе, то это авторская или ненормированная пунктуация. А вот одна запятая перед или после ведь ставится часто, так как же решить задачу?
Предлагаю новый метод, информация NEW!)
Рассмотрим предложение из другой темы:
Ведь(,) если ты забудешь проснуться, тебе никто не поверит.
Нужна запятая или нет? Можно условно считать если ведь составным союзом и  расчленять (ставить запятую) по общему правилу Розенталя для СПП: § 36. Запятая на стыке двух союзов.  Выбор зависит от различных факторов: распространённость, позиция в предложении, желание автора подчеркнуть значимость придаточного.
В данном случае необходимости в обособлении придаточного нет. Аналогично решаются все остальные задачи, в том числе при сочетании с сочинительными союзами вида НО ВЕДЬ.

Спасибо! Скажите, пожалуйста, в предложении "Ведь(,) если ты забудешь проснуться, тебе никто не поверит" - "ведь" подчинительный или сочинительнй союз?

"Ведь" не может быть сочинительным союзом, перечень сочинительных союзов известен.  Они делятся на три группы (соединительные, разделительные и  противительные), и союзы каждой группы  перечислены. В этом предложении при отсутствии запятой это не союз, а усилительная частица, отнесенная к  подчинительному союзу ЕСЛИ.  При постановке запятой ВЕДЬ относится к главной части и входит в состав двойного союза ЕСЛИ...ВЕДЬ (= ЕСЛИ...ТО).

А в каких случаях бывает обособление придаточного с союзом "ведь"?

На этот вопрос я дала ответ: Выбор зависит от различных факторов: распространённость, позиция в предложении, желание автора подчеркнуть значимость придаточного или, напротив, добавочный характер сообщения..  В начале предложения обычно запятой нет.  Но вот пример с запятой:  "Ведь, если разобраться, это лишь дело времени, которого у каждого из нас скоро будет хоть отбавляй".  У придаточного второстепенная роль, основное содержание в главном предложении.

Можно с двух сторон, можно с одной. Главное, чтоб после "ведь" была запятая.

150 цитат
Из них 8 цитат, где с двух сторон запятая
